# Typeorm find options with order and where

Tags: node.js, sorting, entity, relationship, typeorm

I would like to order this find function through the table relation.

```
const [people, total] = await typePersonServiceInstance.find(
  {
    take,
    skip,
    where: (qb: any) => {
      qb.where('person.type IN (:...type)', { type });
      qb.andWhere('person.status IN (:...status)', { status });
      if (query.search) {
        qb.andWhere(new Brackets((subQb) => {
          subQb.where('name like :name', { name: `%${query.search}%` });
          subQb.orWhere('fantasyName like :fantasyName', { fantasyName: `%${query.search}%` });
          subQb.orWhere('person.city like :city', { city: `%${query.search}%` });
          subQb.orWhere('person.state like :state', { state: `%${query.search}%` });
          subQb.orWhere('person.id = :id', { id: query.search });
        }));
      }
    },
    order: {
      person: {
        status: 'ASC'
      }
    }
  },
);
```

The issue i'm facing is when trying to order by some attribute from `person` table, if I do

```
order: {
  anyColumnFromTypePersonHere: 'ASC' | 'DESC'
}
```

It works pretty fine, but if I want to order by status (that is an attribute from person) it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:

```
qb.addOrderBy('person.status', "ASC") ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).